# How to get the first date in a timeline from one sheet to another?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel file that contains multiple sheets.
1 sheet with summary data (front page) and multiple work sheets with the same template but different names.In the work sheets there is timelines for a project, where coworkers has to put in their deadlines. See example;

[image]

Here the next deadline is 16/12

This deadline should appear in the front page. See example (next deadline, the date should be 16/12 here)

[image]

How can I do so? I dont use VBA

Comment: No it does not help me